# Trouble with rownum in query

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I haae this quirk with rownum :

```
select rownum as n, s.* from vzwnet.site_inst s where n between 2 and 10 --> dones not work
```

I have to put it as :

```
select * from (select rownum n, t.* from table t) where n between 2 and 10
```

This will slow it down a lot. Why is that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why do you think this will slow it down?  Oracle doesn't necessarily instantiate subqueries.

There are two reasons why you have to write it with the subquery.  The first is that you cannot use variables defined in the `select` clause in the `from` clause.  To do this, you need the subquery.

The second is that you cannot say `where rownum between 2 and 10`.  The value of `rownum` is set when data is returned from the `select`.  If there is no first row returned, then the second never appears.

If you are concerned about performance, you can do this:

```
select *
from (select rownum n, t.*
      from table t
      where rownum <= 10
     )
where n between 2 and 10
```

EDIT:

Using `rownum` without an `order by` returns an arbitrary set of rows, that might vary from one execution to the next.  It does not return a "random" set (which is much harder to do).  It might seem to return the first rows inserted into the table, but that is not guaranteed.

I am leaving the solution in this form, because the question was about "returning no rows" not which rows are returned.  However, without an `order by` this is equivalent (as Rob says in a comment) to `rownum <= 9`.

Comment: Do you ever sleep?  I figured I'd have a chance at answering some SQL questions late at night, but NOOOOO.  ;)

Comment: In addition: 1) rownum without an ORDER BY clause is meaningless.  2) Correctness first, performance second!

Comment: Depends on the author's intent. It is meaningless without an ORDER BY if the intent is to get specific rows. But if the intent is just to label the rows returned, then that is different. The question as presented does not specify the intent. This solution just labels the rows, in which case no subquery is required. Add an ORDER BY to the inner query, and the meaning changes and this would make more sense.

Comment: Without the ORDER BY, he should have written rownum <= 9. Which also returns 9 random rows.

Comment: @RobvanWijk . . . I edited the answer.  The rows are not "random", they are arbitrary (it is much harder to get random rows).

Comment: @GordonLinoff You're right: arbitrary is a better word than random here

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking to number your records between 2 and 10, there is no need to subquery:

```
SELECT rownum + 1 AS n, s.*
  FROM vzwnet.site_inst s
  WHERE rownum < 10
```